# Scheduling my AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I can see this has been asked before, but I am still struggling to find an answer.

I have a button that executes my AsyncTask. The AsyncTask has a loop that runs in the doInBackground, fetching some data from a server.

This all works really well, but it only works when a button is pushed at the moment. I want this to run every hour, after the button is pushed, until the user presses a second button that stops the process.

Can someone help me with how I can go about executing my AsyncTask every hour please?

I was trying to use a broadcastreceiver, but this wouldn't work and I read that this is not a good idea also.

Comment: You should use a scheduled service http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html.

Comment: @eduyayo: That will only work while the app's process is running. For an every-hour event, the app's process may well go away between events.

Comment: yup, you´re right... Alarms go better but not stated in the text though :(

Comment: If you have a loop inside an asynctask consider using Executors instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The AsyncTask has a loop that runs in the doInBackground, fetching some data from a server.

A loop within `doInBackground()` is not an appropriate use of `AsyncTask`. `AsyncTask` is for "transactional" sorts of work, so the `AsyncTask`'s thread can be returned to the thread pool in a timely fashion. If you want to have a `Thread` that runs for a longer period of time, use a `Thread`, possibly managed by a `Service`.

> I want this to run every hour, after the button is pushed, until the user presses a second button that stops the process.

Use `AlarmManager` to set up your every-hour schedule. Please consider using inexact alarms to reduce the battery cost of this work. If you use a `_WAKEUP`-style alarm (e.g., `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP`), you will need to use a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and an `IntentService` for your work, moving your `doInBackground()` logic from the `AsyncTask` to `onHandleIntent()` of the `IntentService`.

[This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/WakeCast) demonstrates the process, though in this case, the events are set up on first run of the app and on reboot. In your case, you would schedule the events and cancel the events when the button is pressed.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I checked out your code and I think I can make it work, well, thought I could make it work.

I'm getting an error in my AndroidManifest. PollReceiver is not assignable to BroadcastReceiver. So far I've just copied in the 3 java files to start integrating into my project and edited my AndroidManifest.

Comment: Please ignore that comment. I was being impatient. I hadn't examined your build gradle. I have sorted that now. I'll crack on and see how it goes. Thanks for the code, it's really helping.
:D

Comment: I have it working perfectly!. Can you tell me what I would do to stop the alarm?

Comment: @user3572565: Call `cancel()` on `AlarmManager` with an equivalent `PendingIntent` to the one you used to schedule the alarm in the first place.